# Play audio file in PhoneGap(react)

Tags: cordova, reactjs, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have a problem with react. When I am trying to **read** audio file in Phonegap android apk file I am always getting the problem:

```
E/MediaResourceGetter: Unable to read file: file:///android_asset/www/185cee6241898184ab5373e74bcd4499.mp3
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

But this file is exist.

I wrote this rows in config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~3.0.0" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media" />
```

**UPDATE**

I have a music file in `../src/app/music/game.mp3`.
I am importing the file in a component like this:

```
import GameAudio from '../src/app/music/game';
```

Then I use Audio class:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = GameAudio;
  audio.play();
}
```

To build project I am using `build.phonegap.com`

But, anyway, I couldn't **read** this audio file. What is wrong? Can someone help me?

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App?
Are you using the Desktop App? What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: Please also include the Javascript that is in your webpage.

Comment: @Erik Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the Desktop App? What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using CLI **OR** SDK?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650, it's not my first app which was built using Phonegap.
I use Phonegap(web + ios + android). Android 4.0.3, iOS 8. Using Phonegap CLI.

Comment: @Erik you wrote in you Post that you used `build.phonegap.com` now you say `Phonegap CLI`. Please clarify.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650, sorry, I'm using build.phonegap.com. In a archive file(game.mp3) exist. In .apk file file(game.mp3) exist on a loading path (file:///android_asset/www/185cee6241898184ab5373e74bcd4499.mp3)

Comment: So you are **NOT USING CLI**?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106690/discussion-between-erick-voodoo-and-jessemonroy650).

Comment: No. Please answer the question. So I can fix your question and give you an answer.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650, Yes, I don't use CLI

Comment: This is not Javascript `import GameAudio from '../src/app/music/game';` what are you doing?

Comment: do you want to resolve your issue?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650, but in web version this audio file can be read by Audio class(I can play imported file in web)

Comment: Okay. this is worst than I thought. You have several major misunderstandings about how phonegap works. First there are no classes in Javascript. There are in in the new ECMA6, but none othe modern browsers support that (at least not without shim).  FWIW: this is so bad I am going to recommend we discontinue this thread and move to [Nitobi forum for Phonegap Build](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi). At this forum there will be more people to help, beside me. AGAIN, you have multiple misunderstanding about how Phonegap works.

Comment: To be clear, I am not going to answer any more questions on this thread.